# using a Bit Vector in scheme

Tags: vector, functional-programming, scheme

So I'd like to generate a bit vector in scheme. Then take a somethings value after a hash function h(v) = X . Then set that position in the bit-vector from 0 to 1. Any ideas on how to create a bit vector and then manipulate specific positions in the vector? Thanks

Comment: Im using    make-vector size. to create the bit vector. Now I'd like to return the index values that are true, for example 0 0 1 0 1 = '(2 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, we can use a `vector` data structure to represent a bit vector in Scheme, refer to your interpreter's [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html). As a first step, create a new `vector` with the maximum number of elements that you expect, and initialize it with zeroes. For example, to create a vector of size `10` do this:

```
(define bit-vector (make-vector 10 0))
bit-vector
=> '#(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

To set an index in a given value use `vector-set!`. Let's say that we want to set the index `3` with a value of `1`, and notice that the `!` at the end (pronounced *bang!*) indicates that this procedure mutates the vector in-place:

```
(vector-set! bit-vector 3 1)
bit-vector
=> '#(0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

And finally, to retrieve the value at a given index we use `vector-ref`:

```
(vector-ref bit-vector 3)
=> 1
```

For the second part: how can we obtain a list of the indexes where the values are true? there are several ways, all involving traversing the vector, testing the value at each position and accumulating the result in a list. For example, using explicit recursion:

```
(define (true-indexes bit-vector)
  (let loop ([idx (sub1 (vector-length bit-vector))] [acc '()])
    (cond ((negative? idx) acc)
          ((= (vector-ref bit-vector idx) 1)
           (loop (sub1 idx) (cons idx acc)))
          (else
           (loop (sub1 idx) acc)))))
```

If you're lucky and use a sophisticated Scheme interpreter we can write an idiomatic solution in terms of iterations and comprehensions. For example, in Racket:

```
(define (true-indexes bit-vector)
  (for/list ([(val idx) (in-indexed bit-vector)]
             #:when (= val 1))
    idx))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(true-indexes (vector 0 0 1 0 1))
=> '(2 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you want a vector of binary numbers, if that's the case:

```
(let ((vec (make-vector n 0)))
  (vector-set! vec x 1)
  vec)
```

In the case you need a bit vector, I have only seen them in [guile](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/guile/guile_240.html) & [chiken scheme](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/iset), and the interfaces are different.

Comment: to get the index of true values ned something like:(filter (lambda (x) (>= x 0)) (map (lambda (e,i) (if (eq e 1) i -1)) (vector->list vec) (in-range (vector-lenght vec))))